# Streamlining OIDC with Identity Server 4 & Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, angular5, identityserver4, openid-connect

Hi I'm trying to implement an Angular5 frontend that has a Sign In page that Authenticates users using an Authentication Api. The Auth Api is built using Identity Server 4 & Identity with .Net Core 2, it will then be able to use a protected APIs.

My understanding is that I should be using OIDC with an Implicit flow to Authenticate with Identity Server from the Angular UI. It should look something like the diagram on the left. While I would like a more streamlined and native login feel more maybe something like what is on the right
[image: security flows]

I'm trying to avoid the redirect from Identity Server to my apps login page and then back to the UI. Ideally what I want is to be able to POST my user credentials from Angular to Identity Server, this will get authenticated and the token & claims will be returned, cutting out the flow in the Blue Box between the Login Page & Identity Server.

I plan on supporting external logins and if the user is using external authentication such as Google etc, that's fine, I'm ok with a redirect. But I want to avoid it for Users who are using my sites login.

Sorry for the upcoming open question, but I'm at the stage whee I don't know what I don't know regarding Authentication & Authorization. It is possible there is a name for what I want, I just don't know it.

Am I using the correct technology / flow for this? How should I be implementing the type of flow I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more "streamlined" approach you would like can be achieved using "Resource-owner flow" in OAuth 2.0. But for many reasons you should avoid using this.

- User is entering the username/password in a different domain than login server, and this is a security concern
- When implementing features such as reset password, forget password or account lockout features you may have to redirect to login - otherwise when you add several more clients it will be confusing
- The idea is completely abstracting out authentication from client applications, so you do not have to worry about implementing any auth logic in apps.